# Interface field with alternative types

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to define something like this in TypeScript?

```
interface A {
    x: string | number;
}
```

I would like the interface `A` to have a member field named `x` which can be either a `string` or a `number`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the current released version. You need to use *any* for now. But in the next version there is support for Union types with exactly that syntax

More: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2014/11/18/what-s-new-in-the-typescript-type-system.aspx